# Null Pointer Exception at Junit test with fileSystem and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, junit, nullpointerexception, zip

This is my File system code:

```
  public String fileBackup(byte[] fileContent, String name) {
        String status = "Created file...";
        String file = (env.getProperty("file.path"))+ name;
        File srcfile = new File(file);
        try {
             String archive = (env.getProperty("file.archivePath")) + name;
             File destFile = new File(archive);
             //System.out.println(destFile);
             if (destFile.exists()) {
                  return "alreadyExists";
             } else {
                 destFile.createNewFile();
                  BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile));
                  stream.write(fileContent);
                  stream.close();
                  srcfile.delete();
             }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             status = "Failed to create file...";
             Logger.getLogger(FileSystemHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return status;
  }
```

Imported Junit 4.12 and springframework mock. but while running junit test getting NullPointer Exception at   `String archive = (env.getProperty("file.archivePath")) + name;` Accessing path from application.properties. Test code is below.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.mock.web.*;
import prj.iopo.filesystem.FileSystemHandler;

public class TestFileSystemHandler {
    FileSystemHandler fsh = new FileSystemHandler();
@Test
    public void testBackup() {
        FileInputStream inputFile;
        try {
            inputFile = new FileInputStream("D:\\LAB\\job\\8972067.zip");
            MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "8972067.zip", "application/zip", inputFile);
            byte[] fileContent = file.getBytes();
            String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
            String backupOutput = fsh.fileBackup(fileContent, name);
            assertEquals("Backup Created", backupOutput);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Stack Trace of Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   prj.iopo.filesystem.FileSystemHandler.listVersionRestore(FileSystemHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   prj.iopo.testcase.TestFileSystemHandler.testListVersionRestore(TestFileSystemHandler.java:20)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: Where is the StackTrace of NullPointerException?

Comment: I have edited and added stacktrace

Comment: Hmm, the NPE is in the `listVersionRestore`-method, but the code-snippet you've posted is the `testBackup`-method.. :S

Comment: Check line#101 of `FileSystemHandler.java` for null value.

Comment: Your test instantiates `fsh` via `new FileSystemHandler()`, so Spring is not involved in creating the object - `env` is null as the (presumed, since invisible) `@Autowired` annotation is effectively useless. You'll have to use a Spring-aware JUnit runner.